# local.xml not working in Magento 1.9.2.2 RWD

Tags: xml, magento

I use Magento 1.9.2.2 with RWD package.
Seems that local.xml is not working.
If I copy the original catalog.xml to the directory with the local.xml, changes on catalog.xml are effectuated.

This is the code of the local.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

<default>
    <!-- remove the language and store switcher and footer links blocks, we won't use them -->
    <remove name="store_language" />
    <remove name="store_switcher"/>
    <remove name="footer_links" />
</default>

<default>
<reference name="right">
<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
<remove name="left.reports.product.viewed" />
<remove name="catalog.product.related" />
</reference>
</default>
```

Maybe I have placed the local.xml in the wrong place?

Hope anybody has a clue,
Els

[image: This is where I placed the local.xml]

Comment: It should have worked, if you have activated your custom theme and have assigned the layout folder from design area

Comment: As K.C. says + clear cache

Comment: It's driving me crazy: all cache is cleared, as are the indexes, logged in and logged out. Problem still is: local.xml does not do anything. If I make the changes in My Custom Theme -> catalog.xml, it works fine. I remember I have read somewhere that local.xml is not working in 1.9.2.2. Is that correct? Is it OK to change the catalog.xml in My Custom Theme? Hope anybody has a clue.

Comment: K.C. and Roy: thanks for your advice. I got this answer from SeStro in magento.stackexchange.com: Try to put 'remove' nodes to 'reference' node ('store_language' to 'header', 'store_switcher' and 'footer_links' to 'footer'). It sholud works, because 1.9.2.2 doesn't have any problems with local.xml files. If after all it will not work, you could do anything you want with 'catalog.xml' file in your custom template ;] – SeStro Nov 30 at 20:57 . That works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from SeStro in magento.stackexchange.com:

> Try to put 'remove' nodes to 'reference' node ('store_language' to
>   'header', 'store_switcher' and 'footer_links' to 'footer'). It sholud
>   works, because 1.9.2.2 doesn't have any problems with local.xml files.
>   If after all it will not work, you could do anything you want with
>   'catalog.xml' file in your custom template ;] – SeStro Nov 30 at 20:57

That works perfect.